# got some kind of javascript error but idk whats wrong

Tags: javascript

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) 
  if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie";
}

else if(choice1 === "rock") {

    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
        return "rock wins";
    }
    else {
        return "paper wins";
    }

}
```

this code is from codeacademy https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-Bthev-mskY8/1/2?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: You're missing the `{` at the start of your function.

Comment: and at the end also `}`

Comment: @pointy could you post me the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct one.

```
 var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
      if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie";

      }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {

        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the function brackets { }

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if(choice1 === choice2) {
return "The result is a tie";
}
else if(choice1 === "rock") {

if(choice2 === "scissors") {
    return "rock wins";
}
else {
    return "paper wins";
   }
  }
};
```

hope this helps.